# How to reschedule a notification starting from a specific date in Flutter Local Notifications?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I have recently been working on a new project which involves the package Flutter Local Notifications. Everything works smoothly except for one issue. My project involves a daily notification that alerts the user to open the app to check something off for that day. The issue is that when a user checks off the box prior to the time of the notification, the notification still shows up, which is not ideal for my project.

I am currently using zonedSchedule with

```
matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time
```

and trying rescheduling a notification after the user checks the box before the time the notification is supposed to show, however, this just schedules it for the same time again. I want to reschedule the notification and "ignore" or exclude the notification from that day and reschedule it for the next. I have already tried to use WorkManager to schedule the rescheduling of the notification after the time it is supposed to go off, but this is not working properly on all devices in the background. How should I go about accomplishing this task?

Thank you in advance for the help!